# Get text from select tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have two dropdown menus named date and time respectively. I want to get the
text from the option tag when I click a button, but the javascript function does not seem to work. I 've found similar questions (and answers) about this but nothing worked. The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function collectData() {
    var index = document.getElementById("date").selectedIndex;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").options[index].text;
    window.alert("You selected: " + date);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="date">
    <option value="1">date 1</option>
    .....
    </select>

    <select name="time">
    <option value="1">time 1</option>
    .....
    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="collectData()">Get data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the element by id but you didn't assign the id anywhere.

You need to add the correct id to the item:

```
<select id="date" name="date">
....
<select id="time" name="time">
```

Or you could select the items by name:

```
var index = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].selectedIndex;
```

Note: getElementsByName returns an array, thats why the `[0]` was added to select the first item that has that name.

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function collectData() {
        var e = document.getElementById("date");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        window.alert("You selected: " + strUser);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="date" id="date">
        <option value="1">date 1</option>
..

        </select>

        <select name="time">
..
        </select>

        <button type="button" onclick="collectData()">Get data</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `getElementById('date')`.so add id attribute to select element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function collectData() {    
    var ddl = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
    var text = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    window.alert("You selected: " + text);
}
```

```html
<select id="dateSelect" name="date">
    <option value="1">date 1</option>
    <option value="2">date 2</option>
    <option value="3">date 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="collectData()">Get data</button>
```

Here a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNjPvM)